# QlikView - Display datas from a field of a table

Tags: charts, selection, qlikview

Can you help me to know, how can I display data in a chart only for a field of a table ?

For example, I have a table "Country" which have "France, Allemagne, Italie, ...".
In my chart, I only want to display datas from France, without any selection from the user.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select certain values without user interaction with
**set analysis**.

Have a look at the 'QlikView Reference Manual' PDF.

Starting at page 799 you'll find the section about set analysis. 
On page 801 you find the following description:

```
sum( {1<Region= {US} >} Sales )
returns the sales for region US disregarding the current selection.
```

In this case *Region* is the column with your country and *US* is the preselection.

Hope that helps